# When should I put object back to sync.Pool

Tags: go, memory-management, channel, pool, goroutine

I'm passing a big object via channel between goroutines, one goroutine for publishing, many goroutines subscribe and wait for messages, it's so frequent that I wanna use `sync.Pool` to reduce the number of allocations, example code like this:

```
package main

import (
    "log"
    "sync"
    "time"
)

var pool *sync.Pool

type object struct {
    info string
    // other stuff
}

func initPool() {
    pool = &sync.Pool{
        New: func() interface{} {
            return new(object)
        },
    }
}

var (
    lock     sync.RWMutex
    registry = make(map[string][]chan interface{})
)

func sub(topic string) chan interface{} {
    ch := make(chan interface{}, 10)
    lock.Lock()
    registry[topic] = append(registry[topic], ch)
    lock.Unlock()
    return ch
}

// publish goroutine
func pub() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Second)
    o := pool.Get().(*object)
    o.info = "new"
    // do something

    for _ = range ticker.C {
        lock.RLock()
        for topic, chs := range registry {
            if o.info != "new" {
                log.Printf("error")
            }
            if topic == "hello" {
                for _, ch := range chs {
                    select {
                    case ch <- o:
                    default:
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        lock.RUnlock()
    }
}

func run(topic string) {
    ch := sub(topic)
    for {
        select {
        case o := <-ch:
            switch o := o.(type) {
            case *object:
                if o.info != "new" {
                    log.Printf("error")
                }

                // do something
                time.Sleep(time.Second)
                o.info = "used"
                pool.Put(o)
            }
        }
    }
}

func main() {
    initPool()

    for i := 0; i <= 100; i++ {
        go run("hello")
    }
    pub()
}
```

The question is the object borrowed from pool can be accessed by multiple goroutines, so if one goroutine puts it back to the pool after using, it may be modified by other goroutines. I don't know when all goroutines are done with the object, so that I can put it back to pool.

Comment: A pool is really only suitable for resources that are only used by one goroutine at any given time.

Answer (score 2):

One should call `pool.Put()` after he is done with the pooled object, ie it is considered to be "garbage".

If you would put the `o` back into the pool in the `pub` then the next iteration of the loop could get the same object and assign new values to it's properties before it has been proccessed by the `run`. So right place to put your object back into pool is in `run`, after you have proccessed it.

Comment: Use of the `pool` seems OK, however I think you have a bug in the way you use `registry`. In the `main` you launch bunch of goroutines `run("hello")` and I assume that you expect to have 100 listeners for the "hello" channel. However in the `sub()` each time it is called you create new channel and **replace** the current value in the `regisrty` with it (line `registry[topic] = ch`). What you probably wanted to do is to have an slice of channels for each topic in the registry and then **append** to it.

Comment: Now when you "share" object between multiple channels you have indeed problem that it is hard to determine wether it is safe to put the object back into pool. This indicates that your design might be flawed and perhaps you should cosider some other solution...